# How to merge these complex JavaScript array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Can someone help me to do these example?

```
var a = ["17","18"];
var b = ["1","1","1"];
```

I need an output below:

```
var c = [17:111,18:111]
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Your "output" has wrong syntax

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = ["17","18"];
var b = ["1","1","1"];
var i=0;
var ConcateC="";
for(i=0;i< b.length;i++)
{
    ConcateC +=b[i];
   
}
var c=[];
for(i=0;i< a.length;i++)
{
    c[i]=a[i] + ":" + ConcateC;
   alert(c[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please put code in your answer in the future. Link-only answers (even if a jsFiddle) are not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can join the values of `b` together, then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from the indices of `a`:

```js
var a = ["17","18"];
var b = ["1","1","1"];
var bValue = b.join("");
var c = a.map(function(currentValue) {
    return currentValue + ":" + bValue;
});
console.log(c); // ["17:111","18:111"]
```

Comment: This should be the output: var c = ["17:111","18:111"]

Comment: @KingAgustin You should put that in your question. I have updated my answer